# AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument with Paperclip PDF Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to upload a PDF to AWS S3 that is generated in a background process. The error I'm getting is a little cryptic and I was hoping someone had run into this or might be able to lead me in the right direction. I am using paperclip in other parts of the application, but these are taking form data where as this is creating a PDF and saving it to a local temp directory before uploading.

Relevant gems:

- Rails 3.0.9
- paperclip 2.7.0
- aws-sdk 1.3.9

code:

```
MyDownload < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :download,
    storage: :s3,
    default_style: :original,
    s3_permissions: 'authenticated_read',
    s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    path: ":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
    s3_protocol: 'https'

  validates_attachment_content_type :download, content_type: [/application\/(x\-)?pdf/i]
  validates_attachment_presence :download

end
```

During my background process I know the PDF is generated and can be viewed at tmp_path. Here is a little bit of the code I'm using:

```
PDFKit.new(report_content).to_file(tmp_path)
obj = MyDownload.new(date: Date.today)
obj.download = File.new(tmp_path)

obj.valid? # returns true
```

But it fails when I do:

```
obj.save!

(AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument)
  (eval):3:in `put_object'
```

Comment: When I change `s3_permissions` to `:private` it works. I have no idea if this is the same thing though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that switching to the aws-sdk gem requires the s3_permissions option to be a symbol. Changing `'authenticated_read'` to `:authenticated_read` fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this little tip. My headache is going to go away now that I can stop hitting my head against the wall.